# Is there an example?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ and $W$ be Banach spaces and $L: V\to W$ a bounded linear transformation, is there $v\in V$ such that $||Lv||=0$ does not imply that $v=0$?

Motivation: The motivation of my question is to find examples of bounded linear operators (hence continuous) on Banach spaces that fail properties of the norm in their images. This means that a norm cannot be defined directly with these conditions, but perhaps by modifying the structure of the norm a little, that can change.

Comment: Just take a non-injective $L$ and $v$ a non-zero vector in its kernel.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: @Jitendra Singh: I added  the motivation for my question. Thank you for your observation.

Comment: @azif00: Thank you, it's a very good hint!

Comment: @mathproof two things first of all don't include the person name who motivated you to ad motivation and also choose a title that very much summarieses the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $V=C([0,1],\mathbb R)$, $W=\mathbb R$, and $Lf=\int_0^1f(t)dt$.  If $f(t)=t-\frac12$, then $f\neq 0$ while $Lf=\int_0^1\left(t-\frac12\right)dt=0.$

Comment: Oh! It's an example very natural. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Given two Banach spaces, $B_1,B_2$ let $V=B_1\times B_2$ and $W=B_1.$ Then $L:(b_1,b_2)\mapsto b_1$ is a bounded linear operator, with $L(0,b_2)=0.$

Comment: I could not have thought of this example initially, very good example. Thanks!